# Function is not returning any value | C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function that will find the number with max number of divisors but the function is not returning anything. Can someone point out my mistake?

This is the question

Write a C++ program that creates and integer array having 30 elements. Get input in this array (in main
function). After that, pass that array to a function called “Find_Max_Divisors” using reference pointer.
The function “Find_Max_Divisors” should find (and return) in the array that number which has highest
number of divisors. In the end, the main function displays that number having highest number of divisors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int arr[30];
    int* array = &arr[30];
    cout << "Please enter values of the array" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Number with most divisors in array is " << endl;
    int Find_Max_Divisors (*array);
}

int Find_Max_Divisors (int p[])
{
    int count=0, max_divisor, max_counter, prev=0, repeat=0, divisor;
    for (int i=2; i<=30; i++)
        {
            if (p[i]%i==0)
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count > prev)
            {
                prev = count;
                divisor = p[i];
            }
            if (count==max_counter && max_counter!=0)
            {
                cout << p[i] <<" has maximum of "<< count <<" divisors.\n";
            }
        max_counter = prev;
        max_divisor = divisor;
        repeat++;
        }
        return count;
}
```

Comment: You say that the function is not returning anything, but how do you know the function is being called at all?

Comment: @ drescherjm this looks like a regular-old variable declaration to me, it should compile fine :)

Comment: C++ is definitely not easy to parse

Comment: `i<=30` may be an off by 1 error.

Comment: We don't add "SOLVED" to the question title. You indicated the problem was solved by accepting an answer. (I fixed the title.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need pointers to do that this simple code can fix your problem just change the size of your array as you want i am testing with array of size 4 here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Find_Max_Divisors(int p[])
{
    int count = 0, max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < p[i] / 2; j++) {
            if (p[i] % j == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > max)
            max = p[i];
    }
    return max;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[30];
    // int* array = &arr[30];
    cout << "Please enter values of the array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int value = Find_Max_Divisors(arr);
    cout << "Number with most divisors in array is " << value << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
int Find_Max_Divisors (*array);
```

to

```
int value = Find_Max_Divisors(arr);
```

You can get rid of the `array` variable altogether.

It's quite possible you'll find you need to put your function before `main`, too.

Comment: This change alone does not really solve the problem.

Comment: Remember that `int* array = &arr[30];`.

Comment: lol. I missed that. Wonder how OP got so far without helpful warnings from the compiler.

Comment: Many new people ignore the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you declare an array that has 30 elements

```
int arr[30];
```

But here you make the pointer point to the out of `arr`.

```
int* array = &arr[30];
```

I guess you want to make pointer point to `arr`, if i am not wrong, you can do as:

```
int *array = &arr[0]; // or int * array = arr;
```

Then when you call the `Find_Max_Divisors` function, you should change to:

```
int return_value = Find_Max_Divisors(array);
```

One more thing, int this function:

```
for (int i=2; i<=30; i++)
```

When `i=30`, `p[i]` go to out of bount again. It should be:

```
for (int i=2; i< 30; i++)
```

Comment: We can also take advantage of [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) and `int *array = arr;`

Comment: Yes, in this case, i just want to emphasize on his point of view. I mean pointer should point to first element not element 31. I edited. Anw, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code:

- First, if your `main` function should know the funtions it calls, you should declare them previously. Just add a line `Find_Max_Divisors (int p[]);` Before the main function.
- An array in C or C++ **is** a pointer, when you only call it by it's name. So call `Find_Max_Divisors (arr)` and get rid of that awful pointer-assignment.
- In the last line just try to call the function, but never put it to `stdout`, you should change it to this:

```c
cout << "Number with most divisors in array is " << Find_Max_Divisors(arr) << endl;
```

What you actually did with `int Find_Max_Divisors (*array);` was declaring a new variable and not calling a function.